# Program about Average age

Tags: c++

i wrote this code about a program that should print males and females's average age but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Could anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int CountM,CountF,TotM,TotF,i,QP,Age;
    float MediaM;
    float MediaF;
    char Sex[100];
    CountM=0;
    CountF=0;
    TotF=0;
    TotM=0;
    QP=0;
    cout<<"How many people do you want to analyze?"<<endl;
    cin>>QP;
    for(i=0;QP<i;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter Person sex "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>Sex[i];
        while((Sex[i] != 'M'  || Sex[i] != 'm') && (Sex[i] != 'F' || Sex[i] != 'f')){
            cout<<"The entered sex is invalid,enter M o F"<<endl;
            cin>>Sex[i];}
        cout<<"How many years?"<<endl;
        cin>>Age;
        if(Sex[i] == 'M'  || Sex[i] == 'm'){
            CountM++;
            TotM=TotM+Age;}
       else {
        CountF++;
        TotF=TotF+Age; }
    }
    MediaM=TotM/CountM;
    MediaF=TotF/CountF;
    cout<<"The average age of males is"<<MediaM<<endl;
    cout<<"The average age of females is"<<MediaF<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you used a *debugger* ? If yes, then you shoud have seen at least one mistake in you're loop's condition `for(i=0;QP<i;i++)`

Comment: in what situation do you imagine `(Sex[i] != 'M'  || Sex[i] != 'm') && (Sex[i] != 'F' || Sex[i] != 'f')` returning anything other than true?

Comment: you have integer division in e.g.` MediaM=TotM/ContaM;` so MediaM , despite being floating-point, will always have an integer value

Comment: If I insert other letters than m and f it should give me an errore message

Comment: @KingRoy Yes, we understand that. But, the result of specified condition is always  `true`, despite the input. Does the `Sex[i]` could, possibly, contain a value that is both equal to `'M'`, and `'m'`, **at the same time** (the same applies to `'F'`/`'f'` comparison)?

Comment: Reduce your compares, use `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` before comparing

Comment: @ThomasMatthews explain me please

Comment: BTW, you don't need an array.  Keep a *running total* and counter.  After all input is performed, divide the running total by the counter (convert to floating point before division).

Comment: @KingRoy:  `sex=std::toupper(sex); if (sex == 'M') //...`

Comment: @KingRoy We aren't telling you to remove the loop.. Just to refine the condition in said loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; QP < i; i++)
```

This line has a logic error; you want your for-loop to run `QP` Number of times. Hence, you should change the for-loop header to:

```
for (i = 0; i < QP; i++)
```

Another thing: your while loop condition logic is incorrect:

```
while((Sex[i] != 'M'  || Sex[i] != 'm') && (Sex[i] != 'F' || Sex[i] != 'f'))
```

Here, if we see the `Sex[i] != 'M'  || Sex[i] != 'm'`, this will always be true, because even if `Sex[i]` is 'M', it cannot be 'm' at the same thie, hence you will have false OR true, which will lead to the while-loop condition being true, and not falsified, as you would want with the correct input being entered.

Hence change your for-loop condition to:

```
Sex[i] != 'M' && Sex[i] != 'm'
```

This error is replicated in other parts of your while loop condition. Fix that so that it works as expected.

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Er no, he has not, at least it's not showing for me. I still see that error in the for-loop.

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan I did, still see no change.

Comment: @KingRoy please select the checkmark next to my answer, it should turn green when you do so.

Comment: ask @KingRoy he already applied that to the question ..  he is trying to debug the code using the stackoverflow user ,,

Comment: Thanks Man! You're great ;)